# How to deal with A360 authentication API if customer has SSO?

Tags: autodesk-forge

One of our customers apparently has a new option from A360 which lets them use Single-Sign-On. This SSO option, when they login, re-routes them to another site where they can put in their Active Directory credentials.

It sounds good - but the Authentication workflow doesn't work for us because our callback URL never seems to be called. Steps are:

1. We point the user to /authentication/v1/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=.../scope=data:read
2. They put in their A360 user name.
3. They get re-routed to the SSO sign-in
4. They land on their A360 account page

Our callback URL is never called, and they don't even get prompted for permission.

Is there something that WE need to be doing differently? Or is this just a new feature that still needs to be fully worked out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now (August, 2016), this is not support via Forge OAuth API.

Comment: (sigh). But I'll admit this feels a little different getting the news on StackOverflow. It's more transparent. :)

Comment: that's the idea @Matt :-) and, if is the case, mark as answered, thanks.